# Not able to retrieve data from Firebase real time database in Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to the firebase and android studio. I'm working on a project in which I have to fetch details of the current user and display the name. It is throwing "user doesn't exist' toast even if I'm logged in I'm attaching everything below. Maybe I have done some mistakes please let me know. 
[image: Screenshot of FIrebase Relaltiem Database:]

Code to fetch details of the current user

```
public class Succesfully_sign_up extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference reff;
    TextView name;
    Button signout;
    FirebaseUser curr_user;
    String curr_user_str;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_succesfully_sign_up);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
         curr_user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(curr_user!=null) 
       {
             curr_user_str = curr_user.getUid();
            reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userdetails");
            reff.child(curr_user_str).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    HelperClass data = dataSnapshot.getValue(HelperClass.class);
                    if (data != null) {
                        name.setText(data.getFullname_hc());
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Succesfully_sign_up.this, "User does't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
         else
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(Succesfully_sign_up.this,student_signup.class));
            }

    }
}
```

My HelperClass

```
public class HelperClass {
    String fullname_hc,amizone_id_hc,mobile_num_hc,email_id_hc;
    public HelperClass()
    {

    }

    public HelperClass(String fullname_hc, String amizone_id_hc, String mobile_num_hc, String email_id_hc) {
        this.fullname_hc = fullname_hc;
        this.amizone_id_hc = amizone_id_hc;
        this.mobile_num_hc = mobile_num_hc;
        this.email_id_hc = email_id_hc;
    }

    public String getFullname_hc() {
        return fullname_hc;
    }

    public void setFullname_hc(String fullname_hc) {
        this.fullname_hc = fullname_hc;
    }

    public String getAmizone_id_hc() {
        return amizone_id_hc;
    }

    public void setAmizone_id_hc(String amizone_id_hc) {
        this.amizone_id_hc = amizone_id_hc;
    }

    public String getMobile_num_hc() {
        return mobile_num_hc;
    }

    public void setMobile_num_hc(String mobile_num_hc) {
        this.mobile_num_hc = mobile_num_hc;
    }

    public String getEmail_id_hc() {
        return email_id_hc;
    }

    public void setEmail_id_hc(String email_id_hc) {
        this.email_id_hc = email_id_hc;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have created the database manually, your user id **8448....** is not generated by the Firebase android, so it is showing that error. If not then please share the code of creation of that above database structure.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem! I fixed it by setting primary key of data base as Uid. But why getUid() doesn't return the primary key before when I set primary key as phone number? I thought it returns what ever primary key I will set.

Comment: getUid() will always return the ID which is created by the Firebase Authentication system, it doesn't matter that whether ID is used as a primary key or not,  so getUid() will never return your manually created primary key. If you have any query then let me know Thank you

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer then please upvote it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**How about looping through the children and accessing data:**

```
//the reference
reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userdetails");


//the reading

 reff.child.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

 //loop through every possible child under "userdetails"
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

String fullName = ds.child("fullname_hc").getValue(String.class);
name.setText(fullName);

}



}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But I fixed it by setting primary key of data base as Uid. But why getUid() doesn't return the primary key before when I set primary key as phone number? I thought it returns what ever primary key I will set.